# ASP.NET Core Identity, SSO with WSFederation

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, single-sign-on, ws-federation, asp.net-authorization

I need to make my new ASP.NET Core Blazor WASM application authenticate with our on-prem ADFS/WSFederation servers. Specifically, it needs to automatically log-in users that are already logged into our AD domain, *without making them go to a login page*.  Basic single sign on behavior.  (This is how ASP.NET worked by default with ADFS/WSFederation)

I can get SSO to work [without using Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-ws-federation-without-aspnet-core-identity), and I get get Identity to use a log-in screen that will allow you to [choose a WSFederation server as an external log-in provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#add-ws-federation-as-an-external-login-provider-for-aspnet-core-identity), but that still begins at a log-in screen.

Can ASP.NET Core Identity work in an SSO configuration (no login screens appear for domain users), or is Identity built on the assumption that Log-in screens will be used?  If it can be done, how is that set up?  If I can't use Identity, can I still use other middleware like Authorization?